# How to get MySQL status in a query

Tags: mysql, database

Is it possible to use the server status variables in a MySQL query?

I can see various metrics from 'show status' but how do I calculate derived values (e.g. the query cache hit ratio)

```
show global status like 'Qcache_inserts';
show global status like 'Qcache_not_cached';
show global status like 'Qcache_hits';
```

Ho do I get Qcache_hits/(Qcache_hits+Qcache_inserts+Qcache_not_cached)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

generally you can access that info due this select:

```
SELECT
   VARIABLE_NAME,
   VARIABLE_VALUE
 FROM
   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.GLOBAL_STATUS
```

You could make the calculation you want like this:

```
select (g1.VARIABLE_VALUE / (g1.VARIABLE_VALUE + g2.VARIABLE_VALUE + g3.VARIABLE_VALUE)) as result
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.GLOBAL_STATUS g1
inner join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.GLOBAL_STATUS g2
inner join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.GLOBAL_STATUS g3
where g1.VARIABLE_NAME = 'Qcache_hits'
and g2.VARIABLE_NAME = 'Qcache_inserts'
and g3.VARIABLE_NAME = 'Qcache_not_cached'
```

Comment: Darn! "added in 5.1.12" and I've got 5.0 :(

Comment: Since version 5.7 INFORMATION_SCHEMA has been replaced by PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA, this answer can easily be adapted to 5.7.

Comment: You're right. Very good. Feel free to edit my answer. You have 2k rep to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Instead of "SHOW STATUS", use "SELECT VARIABLE_VALUE FROM GLOBAL_STATUS" and proceed like any other table.

This table is located in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` database.

Example query :

```
SELECT VARIABLE_VALUE FROM GLOBAL_STATUS WHERE VARIABLE_NAME="Qcache_inserts"
```

Hope this helps !