# How get status of MYSQL reqest?

Tags: mysql

Immediately apologize for possible stupid question.It's my first MySQL experience.

In a loop, I need to delete one line that satisfies the condition and get the number of failed requests. The question is how to check what ended the query?

```
DELIMITER //
BEGIN
    DECLARE curID INT unsigned;
    DECLARE err INT;
    SET curID = 1;
    SET err = 0;
    cicle1: WHILE curID <= 100500 DO
        UPDATE Syss SET fdel=1 WHERE ID=curID;
        curID = curID + 1;
        IF ??? THEN
            err = err + 1;
            END IF;
    END WHILE cicle1;
    RETURN err;
END; // 
DELIMITER ;
```

Immediately answer, that:

```
UPDATE Syss SET fdel=1 WHERE WHERE ID<=10050;
```

not for me because I have free only 8k on filesystem (and can't add more) and crash even WHERE ID<10...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi please use this link as per your query: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10530987/how-to-get-mysql-status-in-a-query

Comment: What do you mean 8k on filesystem? 8k of free disk space? Have you considered freeing up more space? I don't think you can make it work like this.

Comment: Have you read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/condition-handling.html

Comment: Nothing like jumping in at the deep end